# New SE site for the skeptics in well received opinion (not Fact)

Tags: discussion

Are questions below fit here :

1. What are the benefits if we have no moon ?
2. What are the positives if Axis win WWII ?
3. What are the good things that mosquitoes bring to human life ?.

I think not, because they are mostly opinion based. so I'm considering to create new SE site to think opposite of the current well received opinions of good or bad about something. So we can see clearly about something not only in one point of view but also in the opposite point of view. Do you think this is a good Idea? Will you guys support me there?

Comment: That's basically what quora is for.

Answer (score 8):

What you are describing sounds like it would fit in the genre of [Alternative History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_history). Note: Americans often call it "alternate history" because [they can't speak English properly](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/alternate-alternative/) :-)

> Alternate history or alternative history (British English), sometimes abbreviated as AH, is a genre of fiction consisting of stories in which one or more historical events occur differently. These stories usually contain "what if" scenarios at crucial points in history and present outcomes other than those in the historical record. The stories are conjectural, but are sometimes based on fact. Alternate history can be seen as a subgenre of literary fiction, science fiction, or historical fiction; alternate history works may use tropes from any or all of these genres. Another term occasionally used for the genre is "allohistory" (literally "other history").

This is way off-topic here, because there are no correct answers, only speculation.

[WorldBuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history) allows speculative questions on AH.

[Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history) allows discussion of the genre.

There was already a proposal to create a Stack Exchange dedicated to it. [It failed.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97925/)

I, for one, wouldn't support it, because I think it better suits the speculative discussion in the pub format than the "seeking the one best answer" of Stack Exchange.

Comment: From your own link: *"Alternate can act a noun, verb, or an adjective, that nut. As a noun, it's a substitute, like the alternate who takes over for you in a game or in a jury."* - *Alternate history* makes plenty of sense.

Comment: @fredsbend: From the same link: "No one's going to freak out if you mix them up" <- Wrong! Of course, in descriptivist linguistics, language is defined how people use it, so you have every right to say "Alternate History" is widely used and therefore correct. (But you would still be wrong! :-P )

Comment: I contend that your *alternate* explanation is wrong.

Comment: @Oddthinking Well I think you don't speak English good